# Unable to run maven run in GitHub self hosted runner

Tags: docker, maven, devops, github-actions, cicd

I created the GitHub Actions self-hosted runner in the Kubernetes cluster with the Maven base image.
But when I am running "mvn clean package" command I am getting "mvn not found error".
Even though I tried giving full maven path still i am getting the same error.

```
- name: Build with Maven
  run: mvn clean package
```

Maven base image
`FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim`

The error I am getting when I run GitHub Actions.

````
/runner/_work/_temp/6c9b0c85-4be9-4af0-b168-6dd5bdb998db.sh: line 1: mvn: command not found```
````

Comment: could you try replacing `mvn clean package` with `/usr/bin/mvn clean package`?

Comment: Yes, i tried it.
Still the same error.

/usr/bin/mvn: No such file or directory

Comment: That is strange. This would indicate that the runner is not using the correct docker image. I just double-checked and `maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim` has the `mvn`-executable under `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: Maven home: /usr/share/maven
This is my Maven home path, So I tried this path also.
```
Run /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn clean package
/runner/_work/_temp/91033eef-e7e3-4689-b55d-6a6e50d47bf8.sh: line 1: /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn: No such file or direc
```